# Symfony2 Form Dropping Entity Data

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

This questions is NOT about how to embed an entity that is simple and straightforward my question is about an abnormality I am seeing and can't reconcile.

I have an Entity (Contact) I have an "Email" relation on this and want to have the ability to embed Emails in my create new method.

So I do the usual embed steps:
1) Add my collection to my form (contactType.php)

```
->add('emails', 'collection', array(
       'type' => new EmailType()
      ))
```

2) In the Controller I add a new empty Email entity and set that as my default data for my form

```
$entity = new Contact();
$email = new Email();
$entity->addEmail($email);
$form->createForm(new ContactType(), $entity);
```

This is where the issue occurs, going into "createForm" my $entity has a collection called Emails, coming out the $form is a blank ContactType, no Email attached to it... it's as if the defaultData is just being ignored.

If you have seen this or have any idea why this would happen I would love some input.

Comment: try adding 'allow_add'    => true in your emails   ->add('emails', 'collection', array(
       'type' => new EmailType(),
       'allow_add' => true
      ))

see the symfony doc:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#allow-add

Comment: can you post your entity code?

Comment: Actually I was wrong about the Entity, generating just a default crud the new action created the entire form perfectly, it's only adding a collection that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

We have modified our getter to return an Associative Array and this seems to break the Form builder, The following breaks the Form Builder:

```
 public function getContacts()
{
    $array = new ArrayCollection();
    $property = (is_array($this->contacts)) ? $this->contacts : $array;

    foreach($property as $entity)
    {
        $array[$entity->getType()->getName()] = $entity;
    }

    return $array;
}
```

the basic getter is just

```
return $this->contacts;
```

Which works, it seems ArrayCollection() isn't a simple Associative Array as we assumed it could be.